# How do I correctly capture video object error message?

Tags: jquery, html5-video

When the URL to the video is valid, the video plays as expected.  When that URL expires, the console shows the error, yet the video error event does not fire.

The console shows that the jquery `.on` events are working, so is there something wrong with the coding of these error events, or is there some other magic that I'm missing?

[image: Developer Tools screenshot]

```
<video id="product_video" data-able-player playsinline data-able-player preload="auto" >
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://xxxx.yyy.com/xxx/SH/SH-001.mp4?Policy=eyJTdGF0...X1dfQ__&Signature=MsO...A__&Key-Pair-Id=xxx" />
    <track kind="captions" src="https://xxxx.yyy.com/SH-001_captions.vtt"/>
    <track kind="chapters" src="https://xxxx.yy.com/SH-001_chapters.vtt"/>
</video>


var video = $('#product_video');
video.on('loadstart', function(event) {
    console.debug('video.on.loadstart');   // This event DOES fire
});

video.on('error', function() {             // Does NOT fire
    console.debug('video.on.error');
    alert('video: uh oh');
});
video.last().on('error', function() {      // Does NOT fire
    console.debug('player.last.on.error');
    alert('player uh oh');
});

var vid = document.getElementById("product_video");
vid.onerror = function() {                 // Does NOT fire
    alert("Error! Something went wrong");
};
vid.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    console.log("<video> error");
    console.log(e.target.error);
    // e.target would be the <video> element
    // e.target.error -- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaerror
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is not a "video" error, per se.  By adding an ID to the `source` tag and adding an appropriate listener, that event fires.

```
<video id="product_video" playsinline preload="auto" >
    <source id="video_source" type="video/mp4" src="https://...video.mp4" />
    <track kind="captions" src="https://...captions.vtt"/>
    <track kind="chapters" src="https://...chapters.vtt"/>
</video>

var video_source = $('#video_source');
$('#video_source').on('error', function() {
    console.debug('video_source.on.error');
});
```

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I just undeleted it, I knew it wasn't a well formed question, but thought I'd give it shot.